# How to convert linq query into a list keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

I have this query which reads all columns(45) and rows(40) in SQL table.

I want to store key as column name and values as column entries in the respective row. Thus if I loop the keys, I should be able to pick specific key name and its respective value

This is what I have:

```
var Query = (from k in K_DB.K_Mapping select k);
var q = Query.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>()).ToList();
```

When I run the code, I'm not getting any error but all KeyValuePair are all `null`.

Comment: Show `K_Mapping`

Comment: You're currently converting each item to `new KeyValuePair<string, string>()`. We can't easily fix that for you as we don't know what you want as keys and values.

Comment: You are not assigning any values to the key value pair, you're just creating an empty object. Instead you need to do `new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value")`

Comment: Btw.: instead of a `List<KeyValuePair>` you could use either a `Dictionary` or - if duplicate keys are possible - a `LookUp` using `ToLookup`.

Comment: Daisy Shipton, I want to get key as column name and value as column value. In this case, if I loop the keys I might be able to pick certain column and its value

Answer (score 5):

You are currently returning an empty `KeyValuePair`

You need to specify what you want in the return like so

```
var Query = (from k in K_DB.K_Mapping select k);
var q = Query.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.PropertyX, item.PropertyY)).ToList();
```

Comment: Alternatively, `.ToDictionary(item => item.PropertyX, item => item.PropertyY)` instead of `.Select().ToList()`

Comment: @VladimirPavelka Yes but it has a different output. A `Dictionary` is different than a `List<KeyValuePair>`. If he has no duplicate yes 'ToDictionary()` is the best solution otherwise `Select()` is best.

Answer (score 1):

One of the slower items during database processing is the transfer from data from your DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the fetched data to only the data you actually plan to use.

You are transferring your complete K_DB collection to your local process. It is much better to only transfer the Key and the Value you actually plan to use before you put them in a KeyValuePair. For this we use [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result = K_Db
    .Where(kdbItem => ...)   // only if you don't want all kdbItems
    .Select(kdbItem => new   // fetch only the data you actually plan to use
    {
        Key = kdbItem.X,
        Value = kdbItem.Y,
    })
    .AsEnumerable()          // move the data to local memory
    .Select(fetchedItem => 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fetchedItem.Key, fetchedItem.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Harald for your input. Essentially,  I want to fetch the entire data form the database table in the memory and process it as it may be desired. Memory will be refreshed every 12 hours to check for a new entry